# undefined variable php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have defined my select name id but when i execute the select query it give me the error of undefined  " ID " . Spend almost 2 hours but i didn't solve this issue any help will be appreciated
i am running my select query on basis of dropdown

```
      <?php


include "connectivity.php";
        echo'   <form action="p_update.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="p_add">';



echo'<select name="id">';
                                       $sql="select p_id from product";
                                       $q = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                                       if($q)
                                        {
                                         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
                                           {
                                           echo "<option value='.$row[p_id].'>".$row[p_id]."</option>"; 
                                           }
                                            }
                                         else
                                        {   
                                    echo'query not executed';
                                    }


//$id = $_POST['id'];
        echo' </select>&nbsp; &nbsp;';
        //echo $_POST['id'];
echo'<input type="submit" name="submit1" class="btn btn-default" align="right" value="Search"></input>';

$query ="select p_type , p_category, title,brand,path,color, price ,des from product where p_id='101'";
$rs12=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs12)){
    $type = $row['p_type'];
    $cat=$row['p_category'];
    $title=$row['title'];
    $brand=$row['brand'];
    $path=$row['path'];
    $color=$row['color'];
    $price=$row['price'];
    $des=$row['des'];




?> 
  <select name="type">
<option> <?php echo $type ?></option>
<option>Cosmetics </option>
<option>Jewelery </option>

</select>

 <?php

            }

        ?>                                  
<select name="cat" >

<option><?php echo $cat ?></option>
<option>lip </option>
<option>Eyes</option>
<option>Cheeks</option>
<option>Finger</option>
<option>Wrist</option>
<option>Ear</option>

</select>


                                    <select name="brand">
                                    <option><?php echo $brand ?></option>
                                        <option>Brands</option>
                                        <option>Revlon</option>
                                        <option>Luscious</option>
                                        <option>Maybelline</option>
                                        <option>Loreal</option>
                                        <option>Mac</option>
                                        <option>Bvlgari</option>
                                        <option>Cartier</option>
                                        <option>Graff Diamond</option>
                                        <option>Mikimoto</option>
                                        <option>Piaget</option>
                                    </select>
                                        <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" value="<?php echo $title?>"/>
                        <input name="color" type="text" placeholder="Color" value="<?php echo $color?>" />
                                    <input name="price" type="text" placeholder="Price" value="<?php echo $price?>" />
                                    <input  name ="img" type="file" placeholder="Image" value="<?php echo $path?>" />
                                    <input name="desc" type="text" placeholder="Description" value="<?php echo $des?>"/ >
                                                            </form>
```

Comment: If you don't have form tags with a POST method, then that could be the reason. Use `isset()` and/or `empty()`. As per your `$_POST[id]`.

Comment: i have form tag 
  <form action="p_update.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="p_add">

Comment: @Brendom but you're not checking if it's been submitted, or if it's there. Also, on which line of code is the error occurring?

Comment: can you please also share the form page code , it will help more.

Comment: Again, use a conditional statement using `isset()` and/or `empty()` on the POST array. Pre-assign a variable to it and check if it's set. Your code should be set inside a conditional statement. That's the reason why you're getting that error.

Comment: look at my code last 4 lines the error is coming there . and also at the line of  $query

Comment: @Brendom Try echoing your $query and see if it is correct or not

Comment: the query is correct ...
i just want to run the select query on the basis of dropdown select but in my $query if i hardcode the value $_POST[id] with 99 its working

Comment: @Brendom : i like to check your code from where you submit this form , also you can try with $_REQUEST['id'] and check

Comment: check i have added the full code

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code and it's working fine please try below code and check if it's work or not for you?

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="p_add">';

<?php
echo'<select name="id"><option value=10>10</option><option value=20>20</option></select>';



//$id = $_POST['id'];
        echo' </select>&nbsp; &nbsp;';
        //echo $_POST['id'];
echo'<input type="submit" name="submit1" class="btn btn-default" align="right" value="Search"></input>';

echo $query ="select p_type , p_category, title,brand,path,color, price ,des from product where p_id=".$_POST['id'];

print_r($_POST['id']);
?>
</form>
```